# Memory addresses in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I cannot figure out what is going wrong here. I am attempting to store 10 integers in memory and then access each of them in order. Here is my current code:

```
.data # Data declaration section
strInMsg: .asciiz "Please Enter An Integer:"

.align 2
memAddr: .space 40

.text
main: #Get 10 integers and store them in $t0
la $t0, memAddr #$t0 - 40 = first element in array
add $t3, $zero, $zero 
add $t1, $zero, 10 

loop: la $a0,strInMsg
add $v0, $zero, 4
syscall
add $v0, $zero, 5
syscall
sw $v0, 0($t0)
add $s1, $s1, 4
sub $t1, $t1, 1
bgtz $t1, loop

#la $a0, memAddr
#sub $t0, $t0, 40
#j QuickSort

sub $t0, $t0, 40 #<--- PROBLEM LINE
lw $t3, 0($t0)
add $a0, $t3, $zero  
addi $v0, $zero, 1   
syscall
```

What happens is it correctly gets all 10 integers from the user, and if I get rid of the problem line it will print the last element as expected because that is the memory address stored in $t0. I thought I could subtract 40 from it to bring it back to the front but it just outputs 0. How can I get the first element?

Comment: Temporary registers like `$t0` and `$t1` will not be preserved across a syscall. Use $sxxx registers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never incrementing `$t0` within the loop, so you'll be writing all values to the same address, and when you subtract 40 after the end of the loop you end up pointing at `memAddr - 40`.
Perhaps the line `add $s1, $s1, 4` was meant to say `add $t0, $t0, 4`?

Comment: sorry I was away for a bit there so I never marked as the answer, but yes you are correct thank-you

Answer (score 0):

You increment the address only at the start of the loop before reading into it, so shouldn't it be something like `-36`?

Comment: Thats what I thought as well but subtracting by any number from 4 to 36 still gives 0. Doesnt make much sense.